# Arduino RC-522 RFID reader - comparing values in a byte array

Tags: arduino

I'm using the following code to successfully read IDs from MIFARE cards to the serial monitor.

```
 #include <SPI.h>      
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

int readflag;
byte readCard[4];           

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance.

///////////////////////////////////////// Setup ///////////////////////////////////
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); 
  SPI.begin();         
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   
  mfrc522.PCD_SetAntennaGain(mfrc522.RxGain_max); 

lcd.begin(20, 4);

    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Main loop
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void loop () {

 do {                                                               
   readflag = checkread(); 
  }
    while (!readflag); 

//If card detected do this

       recordid();
  }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Stores the ID of the card that's been detected in readCard byte array
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void recordid() {
    mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent();
    mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial();
   lcd.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        readCard[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];  
             Serial.print( mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);  

        }
    Serial.println("");
    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  }


/////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Returns 1 if a card has been detected
/////////////////////////////////////////////
int checkread() {
   if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { 
    return 0; }                                        //no card detected

    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); 
    return 1; }                                       //card detected
```

I have 12 cards and the serial monitor is telling me that their ID's are (hex):

3278CE3F
F5C9FD29
2FC640
82BA7A3F
2BD7A3F
52B77A3F
B2E5640
F2DD640
E2ECCC3F
22B3640
2FD640
73D5B7AC

I understand these are being stored in the readCard byte array.

I would like to compare the current value of this byte array to a known value to determine whether an instruction is run (e.g. a blink of an LED)

Something like this:

If (readCard = 2FD640) {
    turn on LED
}

I have been able to do this successfully using this if statement:

if ( *(uint32_t*)readCard == 0x3FCE7832)

for example card one. However, it will not work with the cards with IDs that are not 8 digits long i.e. card 11 (2FD640).

Can anyone help me implement this in code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why `if ( (uint32_t)readCard == 0x3FCE7832)` worked for you; it shouldnt, since you are casting a `byte` pointer to a 32-bit integer. What you should have done is:

- Declare `readCard` as a `uint8_t` pointer and not `byte`
- The comparison should be like this: `if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x3FCE7832)`

But like you said, this wont work for the 11th card. You have to right-pad the reversed literal with zeros, like this: `if (*((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x40D62F00)`. To obtain the reversed literal (e.g. 0x2FDD640), write out the complete byte left padded with zeros to make 8 digits (e.g. 0x02FDD640). Then reverse the order of the bytes (e.g. 0x40D6FD02).

You could also store the card UIDs as arrays in your code and compare them byte-by-byte so that there is no dependence on the size of the UID to create 32-bit ints.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented this but it doesn't work with the cards that are not 4 bytes. i.e. card F2DD640 is not found when I look for *((uint32_t *)readCard) == 0x64DDF200

Comment: @mh512 thats because u arent padding correctly. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) like this:

```
union
{
  byte Bytes[4];
  uint32_t Integer;
} UnionCard;
```

Use it like this:

```
UnionCard Uc;
```

Fill it similar to your `readCard[i]` in the loop like this:

```
Uc.Bytes[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
```

Get the UInt with:

```
Uc.Integer;
```

Comment: Thanks - but I get "expected unqualified-id before '[' token union" when declaring the union as above.

union UnionCard
{
  byte[4] Bytes;
  uint32_t Integer;
};

Comment: @mh512 Oh yes sorry, there was a small mistake. I corrected the code!